# Object toString method and Liskov substitution principle

Tags: java, liskov-substitution-principle

Every class, directly or indirectly, inherits from the `Object` class.

The `Object` class, among the others, has the important method, most often overridden: `toString`.

The question is: doesn't the overriding of this method bring to Liskov Substitution Principle violation with respect to the `Object` class?

I'll do an example.

```
public class Main
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Object o = new Object();
        String s = o.toString();
        if (s.indexOf('@') > -1) {
            System.out.println("OK");
        } else {
            System.out.println(":-(");
        }
    }
}

public class MyClass
{
    private int x;

    public string toString()
    {
        return Integer.toString(x);
    }
}
```

Obviously if I replace `new Object()` with `new MyClass()` the behavior of the system changes.

Comment: Why do you think it violates that principle?

Comment: @Eran I updated my question.

Comment: @Eran. You still haven't explained why you think it violates substitution.

Comment: @MadPhysicist Replacing `new Object()` with `new MyClass()` the behavior of the system changes.

Comment: @zeroOuno. That's to be expected. If something weren't to change, why bother having a subclass and overriding in the first place? The substitution principle tells you how much you're allowed to change while still retaining interoperability. The posted answer does a good job relating that allowance to the contract of the method.

Comment: @zer0uno The API say that for the `Object` class the return string of `toString()` is (in short) "type@hashcode". It does not say that it should be this way for your `MyClass` class or that it is a requirement for the `toString()` method.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Well, it's a matter of taste. `Object` has almost no guaranteed properties. So there is no much to violate either.

If you say that returning the class name *is* such a property that may be violated, then of course, a subclass should not change this. But reading the documentation of Object.toString() turns out that there is no such guarantee:

> Returns a string representation of the object. In general, the toString method returns a string that "textually represents" this object.

So **I see no LSP violation here**.

LSP does not say that a subclass must behave *exactly the same* as the superclass. This would make subclasses entirely useless. It only requires that subclasses *meet the specification* of the superclass.

---

The only thing one could mention is that `Object` enforces a *meaningless method* `toString` *for every object*. A more sophisticated design might have put this into an interface.

I think this design choice is just a compromise, taken over by other languages like .NET as well.

Answer (score 1):

Liskov substitution principle requires only interface compatibility. It does not say anything about underlying behavior. So for example

```
public interface Text {
    String value();
}

public class SimpleText implements Text {

    private final String value;

    public SimpleText(String value) {
        this.value = value;
    }

    @Override
    public String value() {
        return this.value;
    }
}

public class NumberText implements Text {

    private final Number number;

    public NumberText(Number number) {
        this.number = number;
    }

    @Override
    public String value() {
        return String.format("%.3f", this.number.doubleValue());
    }
}
```

You do not care about details of implementation, so you can exchange them this way:

```
//We care only about value() method, not its specific implementation
Text text = new SimpleText("text");
text.value();
text = new NumberText(44);
text.value();
```

Answer (score 0):

Note that if your implementation will throw any exception then it will violate LSP as Object.toString() doesn't throw any exceptions.